# prefixfree.min.js on cdn affects other files

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools, amazon-cloudfront

My website is hosted on cloudfront and i'm using cdn for different locations.

I'm using prefixfree.min.js to solve the css3 codes in the website, but it is giving the issue as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Problem aside: using this script in production is killing your perfs (the perfs in your users' browsers. If you're using a CDN, I guess you're concerned by webperf). You'd better use a CSS prefixer server-side like Autoprefixer (there's a grunt/gulp/etc task for that, too) and avoid downloading and executing this client-side imho.